# Android OpenGL ES via NDK: placement of jpg decompression and binding to texture

Tags: android, opengl-es, java-native-interface, android-ndk

This question is verging on the subjective, but not quite: I hope to hear of others' experience with this (or well reasoned answers should be possible too).

I'm writing an Android OpenGL ES 1.1 app. It uses NDK: the core OpenGL rendering is in  native code, much like the [san-angeles OpenGL sample](http://freecode.com/projects/sanogles) that comes with NDK. I'm using  OpenGL textures that are read into the app as JPGs. I know how this is done, but I'm wondering is the most efficient place to do it (by efficient, I mean quick execution).

To illustrate, here's a few scenarios for binding OpenGL textures based on the input JPGs in my project:

1) The Java code makes a bitmap from the JPG (i.e. decompresses it), and bind and loads the texture using the Java OpenGL bindings. The texture ids are passed through NDK to native code so that native code can use them for texture mapping.

2) The Java code makes a bitmap from the JPG (i.e. decompresses it), and passes the raw image data through NDK to native code, which then binds and loads the texture from that raw image data.

3) The Java code passes through the JPG data (compressed) through NDK to the native code, which uncompresses the bitmap and then binds and loads the texture.

I'm using NDK and native code not for speed reasons, but for portability reasons -- I want my core OpenGL code to work on iPhone and Android, much as in the [san-angeles OpenGL sample](http://freecode.com/projects/sanogles) that comes with NDK. I'm aware that native isn't always necessarily faster than Java code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

** Native decompression of a jpeg will be faster than a Java implementation assuming that both use the same algorithm. The difference, however, will not be substantial. **

For portability I keep as much code as possible native. That way when I move between platforms I have very little to do to create the port. I used SOIL to decompress JPG's in native code and I found performance to be comparable to the iOS version running the same code. Certainly android doesn't seem any slower.

Regarding assets I found that ZIP decompress was very slow indeed. Changing the extension in assets to MP3 sped loading considerably. MP3's thankfully don't get compressed. 
When the Android Package is made, all files in the assets folder are placed into the APK. The APK is a zip file containing the application, resources and assets. When the package is made some files are added to the zip file without compression. One of these is MP3. By renaming your files to MP3 they are added uncompressed and therefore load much faster.

My subjective answer to your question would be

4) Do all of your texture loading and asset management in Native Code using the same code you use for iOS. To decompress the jpegs use libjpeg-turbo or SOIL, SOIL is easier, libjpeg-turbo is very fast.  Access your assets by using libzip and libz making sure that you add an MP3 extension onto every file to prevent zip compression.

SOIL http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html

LIBZIP http://www.nih.at/libzip/

LIBZ available in NDK

libjpeg-turbo http://git.linaro.org/gitweb?p=people/tomgall/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo.git;a=summary

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you explain the significance of naming something mp3? What would automatically zip it otherwise?

Comment: And why does accessing my assets via libzip help? It would be helpful if you'd put any extra info in your answer, rather than comments, because that would be better for others reading your answer.

Comment: By the way, sometimes my jpg data is delivered over the network (HTTP ) rather than from disk, but it may also come from disk, because downloads will be cached on disk. How does that affect your strategy?

Comment: If you can clarify some of the points around my queries above, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Native decompression of a jpeg will be faster than a Java implementation assuming that both use the same algorithm. You would only use libzip and libz for the assets that you ship with your APK. If you download the jpg's you won't need libzip.